# Uploading a file from android take ages before calling a function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, httpurlconnection

I'm having a hard time with calling a function when I select on the files.

When I select on a file, it start to take like 10 seconds before it start to call the `UploadFile` function and then connect to the server, so when I select more files to add, it will take like a minute or so before it start to call the `UploadFile` function and connect to the server which is wrong. It should have start to call the `UploadFile` function instantly and connect to the server when I am adding more than one files.

Below is the full code:

```
public class ComposeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private static final int CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE = 1;
    private RecyclerView mFilesDetailRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<String> mSelectedFilesList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE) {
        try {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            FilePath = RealPathUtil.getRealPath(context, uri);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            //mSelectedFilesList.add(cursor.getString(index));
            mSelectedFilesList.add(FilePath);
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mSelectedFilesList.size());

            Log.e("message.......", "caught this.....");

            upload_File = new File(FilePath);
            FileName = upload_File.getName();

            new UploadFile().execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ComposeActivity.this, "Choose any other file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "*****";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            Log.e("message.......", "FileName...." + FileName);

            URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/fileupload1.php");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(200);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(200);

            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", FileName);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(upload_File);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition:  form-data; name=\"uploaded_file" +
                "\"; filename=\"" + FileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            Log.e("message.......", "FileName...." + FileName);

            //returns no. of bytes present in  fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            //Thread.sleep(5000);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                //int percentage = (int)  ((bytesRead / (float) size) * 100);
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                //dataOutputStream.flush(); //doesn't  help
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                + lineEnd);
            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            if (code == 200) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                upload_success = result.toString();
            }

        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();

            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                cancel(true);
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("message.......", "here....5");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("message.......", "here....6");
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("message.......", "here....7");
        }
        catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("message.......", "here....2");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("message.......", "here....5");

            if (failtoupload == false) {
                failtoupload = true;
            }

            if (sendMail == true) {
                sendMail = false;
            }

            if (UpdateDraft == true) {
                UpdateDraft = false;
            }

            if (saveDraft == true) {
                saveDraft = false;
            }
            Date dt = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String savedDate = dateFormat.format(dt);
            draftDB = new DraftDB(mContext);

            if (mSelectedFilesList.size() == 1) {
                attachments = join("", mSelectedFilesList);

                if (attachments.equals("")) {
                    attachments = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                attachments = join(", ", mSelectedFilesList);
            }


            if (attachments == null) {
                if (mSelectedFilesList.size() == 1) {
                    attachments = join("", mSelectedFilesList);
                }
                else
                {
                    attachments = join(", ", mSelectedFilesList);
                }
            }
            String isImportant = "true";
            String isRead = "unread";
            String UpdateDB = null;
            String draftID = null;



            if (to == null) {
                to = "";
            }

            if (bcc == null) {
                bcc = "";
            }

            if (cc == null) {
                cc = "";
            }

            if (subject == null) {
                subject = "";
            }

            if (message == null) {
                message = "";
            }

            if (draft_id != null) {
                draftID = draft_id;
                UpdateDB = "yes";
            }
            else
            {
                draftID = "";
                UpdateDB = "no";
            }


        
            if (draftDB_id == 0) {
                draftDB.insertDraft(from, to, cc, bcc, subject, message, attachments, isImportant, isRead, UpdateDB, draftID, savedDate);
                draftDB_id = draftDB.getID();
            }
            else
            {
                int id = draftDB_id;
                draftDB.updateDraft(id, from, to, cc, bcc, subject, message, attachments, isImportant, isRead, UpdateDB, draftID, savedDate);
            }

        else
        {
            int id = draftDB_id;
            draftDB.updateDraft(id, from, to, cc, bcc, subject, message, attachments, isImportant, isRead, UpdateDB, draftID, savedDate);

        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Log.e("message.......", "here....6");

        if (upload_success != null) {
            if (upload_success.equals("success")) {
                if (mSelectedFilesList.size() > 0) {
                    mSelectedFilesList.remove(0);

                    if (draft_id == null) {
                        new SaveDraft().execute();
                    }
                    else if (draft_id != null) {
                        if (attachment != null) {
                            if (mSelectedFilesList.size() >= 1) {
                                attid++;

                                for (int i = 0; i < mSelectedFilesList.size(); i++) {
                                    String path = mSelectedFilesList.get(0);
                                    FileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                                    attachment += " attid: " + String.valueOf(attid) + " filename: " + FileName;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Log.e("message........", "attachment......" + attachment);
                        new UpdateDrafts().execute();
                    }


                    if (mSelectedFilesList.size() >= 1) {
                        FilePath = mSelectedFilesList.get(0);
                        upload_File = new File(FilePath);
                        FileName = upload_File.getName();
                        new UploadFile().execute();
                    }
                }

                //Now time to check the upload_File
                if (mSelectedFilesList.size() == 0) {
                    if (upload_File != null) {
                        upload_File = null;
                    }

                    if (FilePath != null) {
                        FilePath = null;
                    }
                    Log.e("message.......", "sendMail........." + sendMail);
                }

                if (upload_success != null) {
                    upload_success = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        this.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is when I select on the file and add more files on my mobile app, I want to call the `UploadFile` function instantly and connect to my server to upload the file in each time when I select on the file. If the server do not response for 10 seconds and the server is offline, I want to store the data in the sqlite database.

I have been told that I should use multi thread and I should also use retrofit. I am not sure if it would be possible to use `HttpUrlConnection` method with multi thread to connect to the server and upload the files.

Can you please show me an example of what is the best way I could use to get instantly call to a function and connect to the server using with `HttpUrlConnection` if that is possible??

Answer (score 0):

You start already wrong with trying to get a real path for an uri.

Remove that code.

Then instead of opening a FileInputStream open an InputStream for the uri

```
InputStream is = getContentResolvet().openInputStream(uri);
```

Comment: thanks, do i have to replace from this `FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(upload_File);` to this `InputStream fileInputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(upload_File));`??

Comment: Can I ask why do I need to remove that code? would it help to make it go much quicker to find the file instead of the real path?

Comment: `Uri uri = data.getData();` That is the uri i talked about. Use it. Do not mess around with File and paths.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but you didnt say which one I should remove and replace it with??

Comment: The FileOutputStream i mentioned was a typo. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, can you please post what i need to make the changes?? How I can call the UploadFile instantly??

Comment: I already told you all you had to do and to change.